# CocoaPods Duplicate issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I just recently reinstalled CocoaPods because I was having some strange issue with installing my latest PodFile (apparently the issue had to with Xcode 7.0).

Anyway, my project will now not build and it seems there is a bunch of duplicates symbols everywhere all of a sudden and I am trying really hard not too freak out lol. There is about 400 lines so I will only copy the first little bit, the pattern is the same throughout and all the different libraries used in my project

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. Cleaning my project
2. Reinstalling and installing CocoaPods again
3. Remove libPods.a

Can anyone please help me? Here is the error below:

Thank you!

```
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FMStatement._query in:
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-FMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FMDatabase._checkedOut in:
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-FMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_FMStatement._useCount in:
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libFMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
/Users/TedMac/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/testproject-bgdrygtyrbfgjfancdtafrzibzkq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-FMDB.a(FMDatabase.o)
```

Comment: You can also try deleting your project's derived data (Window > Projects > [your project] > Derived Data)

Answer (score 1):

Although you have tried removing libPods.a, it seems like you are pointing at the library twice, and perhaps are even building it twice. Look at files listed as duplicates to ensure that they are only included in the pods target. Check your library search path and other project settings to make sure that it won't include it again in your application target. Make sure that all of your includes point at headers and not .m files.